# How to determine the environment in a cronjob

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, environment

I've got an issue on how to determine the application's environment during a cronjob.
I have currently have 2 environments: a production and a testing environment. They both use their own database.

I determine the current environment based on the URL. For example: dev.domain.com sets the environment to testing and domain.com sets it to production.

This works perfectly. However, this does not work for cronjobs. Because a cronjob does not get a domain.

How would I solve this and still keeping things dynamic?

This is what the code currently looks like:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'dev.domain.com' || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'domain.local') {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
}else if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'domain.com'){
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass server name in cron job. 
Example if your current php command look likes.

```
php a.php --uri="/foo"
```

It will become

```
SERVER_NAME=dev.domain.com php a.php --uri="/foo"
```

Comment: This is what my current cronjob command looks like: /usr/local/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/index.php/cron/mailque how will I pass the server name to that? But on the other side, my environment is set in the index.php, not in the cronjob function that I call. So I don't think this will work.

Comment: SERVER_NAME=dev.domain.com /usr/local/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/index.php/cron/mailque should work.